# Remove element nodes in post-order traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have the following HTML (condensed):

```
<div><div><div><ul><li>Text</li></ul></div></div></div>
<div><div><div><ul><li>Text 2</li></ul></div></div></div>
<div><div><div><ul><li>Text 3</li></ul></div></div></div>
```

I want to remove the lowest child elements first, until ultimately removing the parent, then move on to the next parent element and its children. This can be easily accomplished by a simple loop that goes through each child element, removes it, then removes the next child element (i.e. parent of the previous child):

```
var children = $("body").find("*");
var i = children.length;
function loop() {
    $(children[i]).remove();
    i--;
    if (i > -1) {
        setTimeout(loop, 20);
    }
}
loop();
```

The problem with this, however, is that it removes the child elements from the lowest parent element first. [If you were to run this code with my test markup](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/zdL5W/), you could see what I mean.

I want to remove the child elements from the top most parent, then work my way down, therefore reversing the order of the above code. I was able to [somewhat accomplish this with the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/zdL5W/2/):

```
var parents = $("body").children(":not(:empty)");
var i = 0;
var speed = 1000;
function loop() {
    var children = $(parents[i]).find("*");
    var x = children.length;
    function inside() {
        $(children[x]).remove();
        x--;
        if (x > -1) {
            setTimeout(inside, speed);
        } else if (i < parents.length) {
            $(parents[i - 1]).remove();
            loop();
        } else if (i === parents.length) {
            $(parents[i - 1]).remove();
        }
    }
    inside();
    i++;
}
loop();
```

The problem with this code, however, is that it only reverses the order of deleting with respect to the parent element. [If there are multiple child elements within a parent, it will still delete them in the default ascending order (bottom to top)](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/zdL5W/3/).

My question, therefore, is how can I delete all the elements in descending order, regardless of how many child elements there are, in a much cleaner fashion? There has to be a much better approach than what I attempted. jQuery isn't a requirement either. The reason for the `setTimeout`s is because I need a delay between removing the elements. As usual, I probably overlooked something relatively simple, so bear with me.

To reiterate, if the HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div>Child 1</div>
    <div>Child 2</div>
    <div>
        <div>Child 3</div>
        <div>Child 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would want it to be deleted in the following order:

1. Child 1
2. Child 2
3. Child 3
4. Child 4

Comment: Please write some example html code and order in which you would like elements deleted

Comment: @Trojan That is correct. So, remove all the children in chronological order (or by their appearance, top to bottom).

Comment: Is adding a child class acceptable? then your code will work fine http://jsfiddle.net/zdL5W/4/

Comment: @megawac I suppose you could, although I feel that there are other ways that don't require changing classes. But interesting idea nonetheless, I didn't think of it.

Comment: @megawac I actually screwed up the edit to my post. The code you posted is more or less identical to the first code I wrote, which removes them in the incorrect (to me) ascending sorting order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First build a post-order (aka child first) version of the DOM tree using the following recursive function:

```
var nodes = [];

function generate()
{
    $(this).children().each(generate);
    nodes.push(this);
}

generate.call($('body'));
```

Then, iterate as per normal:

```
var i = 0;

function loop() 
{
    $(nodes[i]).remove();
    if (++i < nodes.length) {
        setTimeout(loop, 1000);
    }
}

loop();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zdL5W/10/)

Comment: I think I made a relatively incredibly important mistake in my post. When I edited the post after Xyzk's comment, I had the order wrong in the example of how they should be deleted. [Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/LxkEg/) is running in the same order as [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/LkAnQ/). I updated the post, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm idea in pseudocode:

```
RemoveNode( node) { 
for(i=node.children.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    RemoveNode(node.children[i]);
}
remove(self);
return;
}
```

---

Added actual code according to pseudocode:

```
function RemoveNode(node){
    for(var i = node.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        RemoveNode(node.children[i]);
    }
    $(node).remove();
}
```

---

Pseudocode with breaks to see how algorithm works. No idea why, but I can't make it work with delay.

```
function RemoveNode(node){
    for(var i = node.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      RemoveNode(node.children[i]);
        alert("hi");
    }
    $(node).remove();
}

RemoveNode($(".parent")[0]);
```

Comment: An actual example would be much more helpful.

Comment: @Charlie - I added it. (Not tested yet)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Thank you. I tested this, but I wasn't entire sure how to call it. I attempted `RemoveNode($(".parent")[0]);` but it just removed the entire element in one swoop. I think I'm missing an important step though.

Comment: @Charlie I can't for some reason add any version which would "sleep" for some time, but I added one which will create alert every time it deletes something.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
removeLast();

function removeLast(){
    var o = document.getElementById("root"), p = o;
    while (p.lastChild) p = p.lastChild;
    p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    if(o != p) setTimeout(removeLast,20);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6enK/1/)

Comment: It might, but there's no delay involved (which I why I opted for timeouts, since there doesn't seem like a great way to delay while loops).

Comment: I forgot about the timeout... the timeout goes with the recursive call (edited).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question fully, but maybe this is what you're looking for?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xT3Au/1/

```
var $parents = $('.parent');

$parents.each(function(i) {
    var $tree = $(this).find('*').addBack();
    $tree.sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).find('*').length - $(b).find('*').length;
    }).each(function(j, el) {
        var speed = 1000 * (j + 1 + i * $tree.length);
        setTimeout(function(){ $(el).remove() }, speed);
    });
});
```

I think using classes to know which parents should follow which order would be easier. Otherwise it would be quite difficult to figure out the order. Try playing with the sorting function in any case if I got it wrong.

Comment: When I run your example, it simply removes the parent entirely. What I'm looking for is a way to remove all the elements on the page in reverse order, so removing top most first then bottom most last (descending order).

Comment: What do you mean? It works for me like in your example but starts removing the inner children in descending order. I tested in Firefox and Chrome. What browser are you in?

Comment: I figured. Safari 7.0.1. Nothing in the console.

Comment: Must be the sort function... See if this works in Safari http://jsfiddle.net/xT3Au/1/

Comment: This one "sort" (get it) of works. It removes the lowest children in descending order, but then reverts back to ascending order for the parents of those children. So, it removes the `li` elements from top to bottom, but then removes the `ul` elements from bottom to top.

Comment: Then I don't get what you mean by "reverse"... At which point  should the order by ascending?

Comment: It seems that it reverts back to the normal sorting order once the lowest child elements are iterated through.

Comment: He meant remove in post-order fashion :)