# SetTimeout stopping after one execution of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually this is a problem which was created when trying to answer another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517910/remove-elements-in-reverse-order/

I provided pseudocode and Derek 朕會功夫 provided code. However, when I wanted to add a short delay to code, so that we can see what happens, it stops executing properly. SetTimeOut stops after one execution.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UFfHX/

JQuery Code:

```
function RemoveNode(node) {
    for (var i = node.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       setTimeout(RemoveNode(node.children[i]));
    }
    $(node).remove();
}

RemoveNode($(".parent")[0]);
```

I tried using `window.setTimeout()` and using `function(){}` inside with call to remove node, but it didn't work. At the same time, this code executes properly:

```
function RemoveNode(node){
    for(var i = node.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      RemoveNode(node.children[i]);
        alert("hi");
    }
    $(node).remove();
}

RemoveNode($(".parent")[0]);
```

EDIT:
To clarify, I want to add 2s wait before each call to RemoveNode in below example.

```
function RemoveNode(node) {
    for (var i = node.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       //Something like sleep(2000);
       RemoveNode(node.children[i]);
    }
    $(node).remove();
}

RemoveNode($(".parent")[0]);
```

Comment: is your post the code that doesn't work?  your comments say you added the function() {} stuff..  change your post to be the CODE THAT ISN'T working..

Comment: `setTimeout()` requires a function to be passed, while you are passing in the result of a function.

Comment: This is the code that's not working. It should remove the whole top box in jfiddle with 2s intervals before each call to function RemoveNode. But it stops after 1 call if I use setTimeout.

Comment: `setTimeout(RemoveNode(node.children[i]), 2000);` doesn't do what you think it does. If first evaluates `RemoveNode(node.children[i]);` that return `undefined`, so you actually are doing `setTimeout(undefined, 2000);`

Comment: @some ohhhh... that explains a lot. Then how can I execute the first function with 2s delay between each recursive call?

Comment: Step back from the code and explain simply and precisely what it is you actually want to do. It isn't clear at this point.

Comment: You give it a function to be executed: `setTimeout(myfunction,2000):` and NOT the result of the function `setTimeout(myfunction(),2000);` (unless the function returns a function).

Comment: @MichaelGeary what about now?

Comment: There is no sleep in javascript. You have to rewrite your function that does the work to only do the thing you want to happen during one execution. So I assume you have to save the state somewhere. Then you can call that function with `setTimeout(myfunction,2000)` and in the function you can call itself the same way, until there isn't anything more to do, or use `var timerid=setInterval(myfunction,2000)` instead, but then you have to use `clearInterval(timerid)` when all work is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is to remove DOM children slowly, then here's a simple example of how to do that with a timer:

```
function removeSlowly() {
    function removeNext() {
        var item = $("#top li:last").remove();
        if (item.length) {
            setTimeout(removeNext, 1000);
        }
    }
    removeNext();    
}
```

---

As for comments on your current code:

You have to pass a function reference to `setTimeout()` and you have to pass a time value as the second argument and you have to have the correct number of matching parens.

So, change code like this:

```
setTimeout(RemoveNode(node.children[i]);
```

to:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    RemoveNode(node.children[i]);
}, 1000);
```

When you try to just pass `RemoveNode(node.children[i])`, you are executing that function immediately (that's the the parens do) and then passing the return result from executing that to `setTimeout()`.  Since the return value is not a function, there is nothing for `setTimeout() to do so your function gets called only once.

FYI, you also have all sorts of syntax errors (missing parens and missing arguments) so you need to clean all that up in the rest of your code.

---

In addition, even after you fix your `setTimeout()` code in here, you have several logic problems here:

```
function RemoveNode(node) {
    for (var i = node.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           RemoveNode(node.children[i]);
       }, 1000);
    }
    $(node).remove();
}
```

First, the value of `i` won't be correct inside the `setTimeout()` callback function because 
the `for` loop will have already finished executing so `i` will have the value at the end of the loop.   That can be fixed with a closure.

Then, you're trying to call `RemoveNode()` on children after you've already removed the parent.  What is the point of that?  The children are already removed from the DOM.

You could fix the problem with `i` like this, but I'm not sure what the point is of calling RemoveNode on the children at all when they've already been removed from the DOM.

```
function RemoveNode(node) {
    for (var i = node.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       (function(index) { 
           setTimeout(function() {
               RemoveNode(node.children[index]);
           }, 1000);
       })(i);
    }
    $(node).remove();
}
```

Comment: Look at code execution using my second code snippet (the one with alert). It removes 1 div, waits till you accept alert, removes second div, waits till you accept another alert. I want it to work the same way, but instead of having to press "ok" in popup button, I want the code to stop executing for a second.

Comment: @Xyzk - the `alert()` pauses your JS execution which isn't possible any other way.  You can create a timer that will remove one DOM element on each tick.  I will code up a simple example.

Comment: @Xyzk - here's a demo of DOM children removed slowly: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7yF2T/

Comment: Thank you, together with your other explanations I think I will be able to find solution now.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement what jfriend00 has already said, which is all correct, you may want to look at this: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UFfHX/3/)**.

I am not sure exactly how far you want the removal to go back up the dom and your exact intention for the way the removal will work, but this will delete the leaf nodes and one parent up every two seconds. It shows how to use setTimeout and recursion.

```
    var interval = 2000;
    function RemoveNode($node) {  
        if( $node.children().length > 0 )
        {
            $node.children().each(function(){                       
               RemoveNode($(this));        
            });
        }
        else
        {              
            setTimeout(
                function()
                {                                               
                    var $parent = $node.parent();
                    $node.remove();
                    if( $parent.children().length == 0 )
                    {                       
                       $parent.remove();
                    }
                }, 
                interval
            ); 
            interval += 2000;        
        }
    }
    RemoveNode($(".parent"));
```

**Update**

See this: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UFfHX/5/)**.

This will remove the elements one by one if they have a `removable` class. The `removable` class is so that we don't remove every element up the tree, such as `li` and `ul` one by one. If you want the two parents to remove in parallel then take `.first()` out of the code.

```
var interval = 2000;
function RemoveNode($node) { 
    var $removable = $node.find('.removable').first();
    if( $removable.length > 0 )
    {
         RemoveNode($removable);
    }
    else if( $node.hasClass('topParent') == false )
    {          
        //this is a leaf removable node.
        setTimeout(
            function()
            {                                         
                var $parent = $node.parent().closest('.removable');                                
                $node.remove();
                RemoveNode($parent);                
            }, 
            interval
        );                      
    }
}
RemoveNode($(".topParent"));
```

HTML:

```
<div class="topParent removable">
    <div class="parent removable">
        <div class="second removable">
            <div class="third removable">
                <ul class="removable">
                    <li>Hey</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="removable">
                    <li>Hey 1</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="removable">
                    <li>Hey 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent removable">
        <div class="second removable">
            <div class="third removable">
                <ul class="removable">
                    <li>Hey</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="removable">
                    <li>Hey 1</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="removable">
                    <li>Hey 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The idea was for the function to delete all elements inside the first calling node (in this case, delete all children of `parent` nodes, and the `parent` node itself).